# MySQL query need optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I got this query:

```
SELECT user_id  
FROM basic_info  
WHERE age BETWEEN 18 AND 22 AND gender = 0  
ORDER BY rating  
LIMIT 50
```

The table looks like (and it contains about 700k rows):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `basic_info` (  
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `gender` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `age` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `rating` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`),  
  KEY `tmp` (`gender`,`rating`),  
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The query itself is optimized but it has to walk about 200k rows to do his job.
Here's the explain output:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra  
1   SIMPLE  basic_info  ref     tmp,age     tmp     1   const   200451  Using where
```

Is it possible to optimize the query so it won't walk over 200k rows ?

Thanks !

Comment: how many rows would you get if you omitted the LIMIT?

Comment: @Dave K: if i ommit the LIMIT it'll output ~ 63k rows

Comment: How much time does the query currently take and how much do you need to optimize it?
Is this your own server, or are you using a virtual hosting service?

Comment: @intgr: the query currently take ~ 0.0009 sec. the database resides in my own server. as i said earlier the query is optimized well , the only task i should solve is to make the query to walk less rows than it does now

Comment: Whoa, this is definitely premature optimization. A query that takes 1ms is certainly not going to be the bottleneck in ANY web application.

Answer (score 7):

There are two useful indexes that can help this query:

`KEY gender_age (gender, age)` -- this index can satisfy both the `gender=0` condition as well as `age BETWEEN 18 AND 22`. However, because you have a *range* condition over the `age` field, adding the `rating` column to the index will not give sorted results -- hence MySQL will select all matching rows -- ignoring your LIMIT clause -- and do an additional *filesort* regardless.

`KEY gender_rating (gender, rating)` -- the index you already have; this index can satisfy the `gender=0` condition and retrieves data *already sorted* by `rating`. However, the database has to scan *all* elements with `gender=0` and eliminate those who are not in range `age BETWEEN 18 AND 22`

### Changing schema

If the above does not help you enough, changing your schema is always possible. One such approach is turning the `age BETWEEN` condition into an equality condition, by defining an *age group* column; for instance, ages 0-12 will be in age group 1, ages 12-18 in age group 2, etc.

This way, having an index with `(gender, agegroup, rating)` and query with `WHERE gender=0 AND agegroup=3 ORDER BY rating` will retrieve all results from the index and already sorted. In this case, the LIMIT clause should *only* fetch 50 entries from the table and no more.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, especially about the range condition.

Comment: @intgr: changing the schema sounds reasonable but it's not possible in my case because : what happen if the user says - give me all the users between 10 AND 12, or 11 AND 20 or even 10 AND 40?

Comment: If you want to allow queries over arbitrary age ranges then you're right, it does not help. Unfortunately I'm out of ideas for now.

Comment: @intgr: anyway i +1 because of the good advices + explanations. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Extend you `tmp`-key to include the `age`-column:

```
KEY `tmp` (`age`,`gender`,`rating`)
```

Comment: The `rating` column is useless in this index. Since the query has a range condition on the `gender` field, results from this index will not be sorted, so ther will be a separate sort step no matter what.

Comment: If i extend the key as you propose the query performance degrade. Here's the explain output:  

id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra  
1  SIMPLE  basic_info  range  tmp  tmp  2  NULL  107375  Using where; Using filesort

Comment: @intgr : The rating column in the index save me from the using filesort

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to use InnoDB to improve performence?

Benchmarking [here](http://www.innodb.com/products/innodb/benchmarks/)

Comment: @Shadi Almosri: yep, it's better, but it's "forbidden" to use INNODB :(